# Prefixing meson target_list name

Tags: meson-build, meson-cmake-module

Trying to incorporate a cmake subproject [(VTK)](https://docs.vtk.org/en/latest/build_instructions/build.html) into a meson project using the following in meson.build:

```
cmake = import('cmake')
opt_var = cmake.subproject_options()
opt_var.add_cmake_defines({'VTK_ENABLE_WRAPPING': 'OFF'})
opt_var.add_cmake_defines({'VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_sqlite': 'NO'})
opt_var.add_cmake_defines({'VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_hdf5': 'NO'})
vtk_proj = cmake.subproject('vtk', options: opt_var)
message('CMake targets:\n - ' + '\n - '.join(vtk_proj.target_list()))
```

outputs:

```
Message: CMake targets:
...
 - ChartsCore
 - CommonColor
 - CommonComputationalGeometry
 - CommonCore
...
```

which lists the necessary targets, however other subprojects using this dependency expect the target_list names to be prefixed with VTK::

```
Executing subproject VtkViewer
...
VtkViewer| WARNING: Subproject 'vtk' did not override 'VTK (modules: VTK::CommonCore, VTK::CommonColor, VTK::CommonExecutionModel, VTK::FiltersCore, VTK::RenderingCore, VTK::InteractionStyle, VTK::RenderingUI)' dependency and no variable name specified
VtkViewer| Dependency VTK (modules: VTK::CommonCore, VTK::CommonColor, VTK::CommonExecutionModel, VTK::FiltersCore, VTK::RenderingCore, VTK::InteractionStyle, VTK::RenderingUI) from subproject subprojects/vtk found: NO
```

Is there a way to modify or alias the `target_list` names with meson's CMake module?

An alternative would be a wrap file with the prefixed public names in the `[provide]` section. However, I haven't found documentation for a way to add `cmake_defines` to wrapfiles.

I am trying to avoid writing a meson.build file since the cmake infrastructure for this library is rather complicated.